# Disabling direct creation allowing creation only via NEW and smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

How can we disable direct creation of an object yet allow creation via new and smart pointer?

In other words, I'm trying to see if it is possible to force instantiation via heap allocation.  I wouldn't do this in production, just want to see if it can be done.

By making destructor private, I'm able to disable direct object creation (ex: Test t; ).  I want to force instantiation via new (this works) or smart pointer like unique_ptr.

I believe that I'm doing something wrong with how I'm approaching unique_ptr but I'm not sure what.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    ~Test() {cout << "x" << endl;}
public:
    Test() {cout << "c" << endl;}
    static void destruct(Test* ptr) {delete ptr;}  //Doesn't need to be static
};

int main()
{
    //Perfect
    //We want to disable direct creation. This fails and we want it to fail.
    //Test t;  ERROR: Can't because dest is private!

    //OK   
    Test *ptr = new Test;       //Creation via new works fine
    ptr->destruct(ptr);         //Destruct works fine

    //NOT OK. :-(
    //auto up = make_unique<Test>();  //error
    //unique_ptr<Test> up( new Test(), [](Test* p){destruct(p);} );     //error
    //unique_ptr<Test> up( new Test(), [](Test* p){Test::destruct(p);} );     //error
    unique_ptr<Test> up( new Test(), [](Test* p){p->destruct(p);} );     //error

    return 0;
}
```

The trick above works with NEW, which is old-school C++.   unique_ptr on the other had is turning out to be somewhat problematic.

Comment: You need to make the constructor private and provide a static function that returns a dynamically allocated instance of your class.

Comment: Why are you calling destruct differently in the unique_ptr deleter? `destruct(p)`??

Comment: Rakete1111 I tried various ways.  I don't think this can be made to work with unique_ptr even with custom deleter because it seems to still see the private destructor and bails out. But maybe someone knows better... Maybe it has something to do with how unique_ptr is implemented... or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Why would you want a private destructor? If you don't like people to allocate your class, use a private constructor. The destructor should always be public, anyone should be able to destroy your object once they get it (e.g. by a pointer).

Comment: Frax, it's an experiment to see if you can force people to use dynamic allocation (heap).  It's advanced C++.  I wouldn't do this in production. Just trying to see if it can be done.  It's not about preventing people from allocating the class, it's about controlling how they allocate (stack or heap).

Comment: @DimChtz - IMHO, you should expand your comment in an answer.

Comment: You can solve the `std::unique_ptr` problem with `auto tDeleter = [](Test * p){p->destruct(p);}; unique_ptr<Test, decltype(tDeleter)> up(new Test(), tDeleter);`. But I don't think it's a good idea: I suggest to maintain `public` the destructor, to put `private` the constructor and to create objects through a `static` method or a `friend` function (see DimChtz suggestion).